# URL @Context.Request.Query

Tags: c#, url, model-view-controller, .net-core

i want to add URL @Context.Request.Query for take URL automation fill in to textbox. but when i add URL @Context.Request.Query[] for automation which column data will disapper. for example, when i automation Textbox[Name],[ID] and not tick IsAccept and go to sumbit. the column[Name] and[ID] will Disappear. but if i cancel use @Context.Request.Query[]. it is normal. For example, i manually input the data to Textbox[Name],[ID] and not tick IsAccept and go to sumbit. the column[Name] and[ID] will sill keep all data.

anybody can give advise and help??thank so much!

```html
Controller

public class CheckBoxRequired : ValidationAttribute
         {
             protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
             {
                 //get the entered value
                 var student = (UserViewModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
                 //Check whether the IsAccepted is selected or not.
                 if (student.IsAccepted == false)
    { 
    return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage == null ? "Please checked the checkbox" ErrorMessage); 
     }
                 return  ValidationResult.Success;
             }
         }
```

```html
Controller 

public IActionResult CreateUser()
             {
                 return View();
             }
             [HttpPost]
             public IActionResult CreateUser(UserViewModel user)
             {
                 if (ModelState.IsValid)
                 {
                    //after validation success, create a UserClass instance based on the ViewModel, and insert the "newuser" into database.
                     var newuser = new UserClass();
                     newuser.ID = user.ID;
                     newuser.Name = user.Name;       
                     //save the newuser into the database via dbcontext
                     _dbcontext.UserClass.Add(newuser);
                     _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                     return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                 }
                 return View();
             }
```

```html
View:
             @model WebApplication2.Models.UserViewModel

             @{
                 ViewData["Title"] = "CreateUser";
                 Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
             } 
          <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                     <form asp-action="CreateUser">
                         <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                             <label asp-for="ID" class="control-label"></label>
                             <input asp-for="ID" class="form-control"value="@Context.Request.Query["ID"]" />
                             <span asp-validation-for="ID" class="text-danger"></span>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                             <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                             <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" 
    value="@Context.Request.Query["Name"]"/>
                             <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group form-check">
                             <label class="form-check-label">
                                 <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="IsAccepted" /> 
                             </label>
                             <span asp-validation-for="IsAccepted" class="text-danger"></span>
                         </div> 
                         <div class="form-group">
                             <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                         </div>
                     </form>
                 </div>
             </div>
```

```html
Models

public class UserViewModel
 {
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Entry ID")]
     public int ID { get; set; }
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Entry Name")]
     public string Name { get; set; } 
     //use custom validation method
     [CheckBoxRequired(ErrorMessage ="Please checked the items")]
     public bool IsAccepted { get; set; } 
 }
```

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, but if im not understanding you incorrectly what you want to do is automatically fill the Textbox on the View with a name that came in the query string?

Comment: yesyes! i use  <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" value="@Context.Request.Query["Name"]" /> , it is feasible but when some column i have not input data and go to submit ,The textbox data will disapper

Comment: Helo nalnpir, thanks for your teaching! it is very useful for me to use another way replace @Context.Request.Query, but it is still not work. i have some gif for clearly my problems below .thanks you sooo much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what you told me in the comments, I highly recommend you to do it this way in the controller you should change it to look this way

```
 [HttpGet]
 public IActionResult CreateUser(string name)
 {
     return View();
 }
```

Then you have 2 options,

1. you fill up a viewmodel and you send it to the view, or option number

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public IActionResult CreateUser(string name)
   {
       UserViewModel vm = new UserViewModel { Name = name };
       return View(vm);
   }
   ```

   In the view replace `value="@Context.Request.Query["Name"]"` with this `value="@Model.Name"`
2. You fill the viewbag and then consume it on the View

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public IActionResult CreateUser(string name)
   {
       ViewBag.Name = name;
       return View();
   }
   ```

   In the view replace `value="@Context.Request.Query["Name"]"` with this `value="@(ViewBag.Name as string)"`

It could actually work without the casting the ViewBag in this particular case so it could be only `value="@ViewBag.Name"`

Answer (score 0):

GIF1:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGrwz.gif

GIF1: When i add value="@Context.Request.Query["Name"]" to input asp-for="Name" class="form-control".
it will cause all column data disappear.

GIF2
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGmHU.gif

it is my target when i add i add value="@Context.Request.Query["Name"]"  to   input asp-for="Name" class="form-control".
all the column data should keep

Thanks!